# Checkstyle COMMENT_CONTENT Tokentype usage

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, checkstyle

I am writing some custom checks using Checkstyle, and being able to know where comments are in the source code is necessary. I'm using an Eclipse plugin to view a visual representation of the Checkstyle AST, and TokenTypes relating to comments don't seem to appear.

I was looking at the TokenTypes API page (http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/api/TokenTypes.html#COMMENT_CONTENT) and it seems like a TokenType called COMMENT_CONTENT exists. When I try to extract all COMMENT_CONTENT Tokens, I always end up with an empty result.

Can anyone advise me on how to use the COMMENT_CONTENT TokenType, or how to be able to see comment lines using Checkstyle?